# How to fetch x-csrf-token from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, api, get

I am trying to fetch x-csrf-token so that I could use it in subsequent calls. My script looks like below :

```
Sub ExternalTrigger_Click()
Dim response As String
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Url = "XXXXXXXXXX"
username1 = "XXXXX"
password1 = "XXXXX"
objHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False, username1, password1
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "x-csrf-token", "fetch"
objHTTP.send ("")
response = objHTTP.GetResponseHeader("x-csrf-token")
MsgBox response

End Sub
```

However, I am getting an empty message box. I tried to check all response header with getAllResponseHeaders() and I couldn't find x-csrf-token listed. However, it does exist in header as I was able to fetch it using POSTMAN. Another thing I noticed (not sure if it is related to issue), content type for same API GET request in POSTMAN shows application/xml whereas with VBA it shows application/html.

Please suggest how to get x-csrf-token from Excel using VBA script.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update : After adding authorization in the script, I could fetch the required token.